# Accessing hidden ini file sections (colon on file name)

Tags: windows, winapi, ini

I just stumbled on a piece of code that does something I have never seen before, and I can't find information about this anywehere.

The program creates a regular `ini` file and writes a few things, nothing fancy.

After the file is created, the code further writes data to the file, it dumps a whole 7MB binary file *inside* the `ini` file like this:

```
FileWrite(inifile:binary:$DATA)
```

And that's it. The binary is dumped in the file, and I can't find a way to access it. If I right click the file and go to properties, it says "size: 808bytes" and "size on disk: 7mb", cleary the binary file is there somewhere.

I tried doing something similar and wrote this on the CMD:

```
notepad anyname.ini:WTH
```

Notepad was executed and asked me if I wanted to save file "anyname.ini:WTH". I clicked "yes", wrote a few characters in there and *saved the file*.

A file with the name "anyname.ini" was indeed created, but if I open it, it is empty!

[image: What is this?]

Question: what is this behavior, and how can I access this data?

Comment: What language was this code with "FileWrite()" written in?  What happens if you open the file in Notepad++ or (a better test) a hex editor?

Comment: Autohotkey. But you can do this yourself, just type "notepad file.ini:blabla" and hit enter. Then write a few megabytes of text, save and close it.

Comment: That's called an *alternate data stream*. They're well documented, and a Google search on that exact term will find lots of information on the topic.

Comment: Forgot to answer your other question - you access it the same way you created it, with `notepad anyname.ini:$WTH` (IIRC, the `$` is required, but I could be wrong).

Comment: Awesome man. Thanks a lot. Right an answer and Ill accept it. I had never head of this. Great stuff.

Comment: @KenWhite the `$` is *not* required in an ADS stream name

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. I wasn't sure - it's been a while since I did anything related to alternate data streams.

Comment: You can enumerate the data streams for any given file using [BackupRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-backupread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an NTFS file system, a file can have 1 or more [Alternate Data Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/c54dec26-1551-4d3a-a0ea-4fa40f848eb3) in it.  An ADS is identified by this naming format:

`<filename>:<stream name>:<stream type>`

Each ADS is logically separate from each other, but are grouped together inside the same file.  `CreateFile()` can return a `HANDLE` to each ADS individually when passed their fully qualified names.

In your example, `inifile:binary:$DATA` creates an ADS named `binary` of type `$DATA` in the file `inifile`.  In Windows Explorer, it is showing you the size of the file's *main* ADS only, and the total size of the entire file counting all ADS's in it.

Likewise, `anyname.ini:WTH` creates an ADS named `WTH` of default type `$DATA` in the file `anyname.ini`.

Every file has a main ADS. For example, `sample.txt` has a main ADS named `sample.txt::$DATA` - an ADS of type `$DATA` with no name.  This is the main ADS that users and apps typically work with.

When a file is copied around an NTFS system, its associated ADS's stay with the file.  But if the file is copied to a non-NTFS system, all ADS's other than the main ADS are lost.

See [Appendix A: NTFS Alternate Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/b134f29a-6278-4f3f-904f-5e58a713d2c5) of MSDN's [[MS-FSCC]: File System Control Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/efbfe127-73ad-4140-9967-ec6500e66d5e) documentation for more details.